# MySQL - inner join - add column with value based on other value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, inner-join

I'm struggling with mysql joins :/

I've multiple tables inside database fe. *tasks*, *users* etc.

Table *tasks* containing tasks with various variables, but the most important - id's of users signed to task (as different roles inside the task - author, graphic, corrector):

```
+---------+-------------+--------------+
| task_id | task_author | task_graphic |
+---------+-------------+--------------+
| 444     | 1           | 2            |
+---------+-------------+--------------+
```

Table *users*

```
+---------+----------------+------------+-----------+
| user_id | user_nice_name | user_login | user_role |
+---------+----------------+------------+-----------+
| 1       | Nice Name #1   | login1     | 0         |
+---------+----------------+------------+-----------+
| 2       | Bad Name #2    | login2     | 1         |
+---------+----------------+------------+-----------+
```

Using PDO I'm getting the whole data I want while using INNER JOIN with data from different tables (and $_GET variable)

```
SELECT tasks.*, types.types_name, warehouse.warehouse_id, warehouse.warehouse_code, warehouse.warehouse_description
FROM tasks
INNER JOIN types ON types.types_id = tasks.task_id
INNER JOIN warehouse ON warehouse.warehouse_id = tasks.task_id
WHERE tasks.task_id = '".$get_id."'
ORDER BY tasks.task_id
```

Above query returns:

```
+---------+--------------+--------------+----------------+------------+-----------+------------------+------------------------+------------+-------------+-----------------+-----------+----------------+--------------------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+------------------+---------------------+
| task_id | task_creator | task_graphic | task_purchaser | task_title | task_lang | task_description | task_description_files | task_files | task_status | task_prod_index | task_type | task_print_run | task_print_company | task_warehouse_code | task_cost | task_time_added     | task_deadline    | task_date_warehouse |
+---------+--------------+--------------+----------------+------------+-----------+------------------+------------------------+------------+-------------+-----------------+-----------+----------------+--------------------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+------------------+---------------------+
| 2       | 1            | 2            | 1              | Test       | PL        | Lorem ipsum (?)  |                        |            | w           | 2222            | 3         | 456546         | Firma XYZ          | 2                   | 124       | 29.09.2016 15:48:20 | 01.10.2016 12:00 | 07.10.2016 14:00    |
+---------+--------------+--------------+----------------+------------+-----------+------------------+------------------------+------------+-------------+-----------------+-----------+----------------+--------------------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+------------------+---------------------+
```

And I'd like to get query with added user_nice_name after task_creator, task_author and task_graphic - obviously nice names selected from table *users* based on ID's provide in 3 above fields fe.

```
+---------+--------------+------------------------------------+--------------+--------------------------------------+
| task_id | task_creator | task_creator_nn                    | task_graphic | task_graphic                         |
+---------+--------------+------------------------------------+--------------+--------------------------------------+
| 2       | 1            | Nice Name (from task_creator ID=1) | 2            | Nice Name (from task_graphic ID = 2) |
+---------+--------------+------------------------------------+--------------+--------------------------------------+
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: add a join for the table that contain task_graphic name

Comment: `INNER JOIN users ON users.user_nice_name = tasks.task_graphic`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need three joins:

```
SELECT t.*,
       uc.user_nice_name as creator_name,
       ug.user_nice_name as graphic_name,
       up.user_nice_name as purchaser_name,
       ty.types_name, w.warehouse_id, w.warehouse_code, w.warehouse_description
FROM tasks t INNER JOIN
     types ty
     ON ty.types_id = t.task_id INNER JOIN
     warehouse w
     ON w.warehouse_id = t.task_id LEFT JOIN
     users uc
     ON uc.user_id = t.task_creator LEFT JOIN
     users ug
     ON ug.user_id = t.task_graphic LEFT JOIN
     users up
     ON up.user_id = t.task_purchaser
WHERE t.task_id = '".$get_id."'
ORDER BY t.task_id;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.  They are also required because you have three references to `users` in the `FROM` clause.
- This uses `LEFT JOIN` for the `users` in case some of the reference values are missing.
- You need to work on your naming.  It doesn't make sense that a "warehouse" id matches a "task" id.  Or that a "task" id matches a "types" id.  But that is how you phrased the query in your question.
- The `ORDER BY` effectively does nothing, because all rows have the same `task_id`.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the task_graphic_name is inside a table name  task_graphic_table and the relation field are task_graphic_id

```
SELECT tasks.*
      , types.types_name
      , warehouse.warehouse_id
      , warehouse.warehouse_code
      , warehouse.warehouse_description
      , users.user_nice_name
FROM tasks
INNER JOIN types ON types.types_id = tasks.task_id
INNER JOIN warehouse ON warehouse.warehouse_id = tasks.task_id
INNER JOIN users ON users.user_nice_name = tasks.task_graphic
WHERE tasks.task_id = '".$get_id."'
ORDER BY tasks.task_id
```

And if you need the column appear in a specific order you should explicitally call the column name in sequence eg:

```
SELECT tasks.col1
      , task.col2
      , types.types_name
      , warehouse.warehouse_id
      , warehouse.warehouse_code
      , task.col2
      , warehouse.warehouse_description
      , task_graphic_table.task_graphic_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Add two sub query in with your query. like

```
 SELECT tasks.*,
....
....,
(select user_nice_name from users where id = tasks.task_author) AS task_creator_name,
(select user_nice_name from users where id = tasks.task_graphic) AS task_graphic_name
FROM tasks
INNER JOIN types ON types.types_id = tasks.task_id
....
....
```